# AngularJS radio button value not changed while change my choice

Tags: angularjs

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller("SomeController", function($scope) {
    $scope.formData = {};
    $scope.choices = [
    {
      "text": "Denim",
      "price": "$0.00",
      "isSelected": "false"
    }
      ,
      {
        "text": "Black",
        "price": "$0.00",
        "isSelected": "true"
      },
      {
        "text": "Brown",
        "price": "$0.00",
        "isSelected": "false"
      }];
      
      $scope.formData = $scope.choices;
        
    $scope.save = function(){
      $scope.formData = $scope.choices;
    };
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js"></script>
<div>Choose your choice</div>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="SomeController">
  <div ng-repeat="choice in choices">
    <input type="radio" id="choicesRadio{{$index}}" name="choicesRadio" ng-model="choice.isSelected" value="true" /> <label for="choicesRadio{{$index}}">{{choice.text}}</label>
  </div>
    <!--<input type="button" ng-click="save()" value="Submit" />-->
   <pre>{{formData | json}}</pre>
</div>
```

I have 3 choices `Denim`, `Black` and `Brown` default checked `Black` while page load. When I am changing `Black` to `Denim` my previous Black option `isSelected` value not changed. Pleas check code snippet and let me know how to make any one `true` rest will change to `false`

Thank you.

#### [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/chinmay235/mo3x1z3j/)

Comment: take a look at my solution I used checkboxes.. https://jsfiddle.net/22zy9aka/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this solution helps you.

**HTML code**

```
<div ng-repeat="choice in choices">
     <input type="radio" id="choicesRadio{{$index}}" name="choicesRadio" ng-model="choice.isSelected" ng-value="true" ng-click="setChoice(choice)" /> <label for="choicesRadio{{$index}}">{{choice.text}}</label>
</div>
```

**Code in controller**

```
$scope.setChoice = function (c) {
   angular.forEach($scope.choices, function (c) {
        c.isSelected = false;
   });
   c.isSelected = true;
};
```

Comment: Working fine. Thank you dear.

Comment: You are welcome. Can you accept the answer if it helped you?

Answer (score 0):

With angular, the right way to declare input is not to put them into a ng-repeat.

You need to put the "ng-repeat-start" and "ng-repeat-end" ;) 
Try the following : (not validate on plunker but should work)

```
<input type="radio" ng-repeat-start="choice in choices" id="choicesRadio{{$index}}" name="choicesRadio" ng-model="choice.isSelected" value="true" /> 
<label for="choicesRadio{{$index}}" ng-repeat-end>{{choice.text}}</label>
```

In fact, the previous snippet is working like yours. 
I just realize that you have an attribute "value" identical for all your option.

So, when you click, angular just set "true" in the variable binded with "ng-model". So, you put "true" on each click, but nothing more.

If you want to know wich one is check, take a fix variable for your "ng-model" attribute, not one wich will change with your option.

(i will try to edit your jsfiddle)

Comment: In fact, you have an other problem too.